# How to add & remove windows 10 pin sign-in?

Tags: login, windows-10-preview, pin

I'm testing windows 10 build 9926. Fresh install.
I'm having problems with pin sign-in option.

1. I've added a pin and restarted it and could only sign-in with password.

2. I tried to remove my pin sign-in, but I couldn't find the option, do anyone know if it exist?

Comment: to disable pin select I forgot my pin then click continue then click cancel
then its gone :)

Answer (score 7):

I've also had the same problem, and got it solved through this process:
`Settings->Accounts->Sign-in options->`
 I forgot my PIN.

After the PIN reset, the PIN option is back on Login screen.

Comment: This worked for me.  If you simple reset/change your PIN, it doesn't fix the problem. You have to tell it you forgot your PIN.  It will make you enter your password and a new PIN. Then the option will show up allowing a PIN to be entered.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to remove the PIN, you must cancel out on the screen where you're supposed to type in the new PIN.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently a know issue for build 9926, reported in the comments of this article:

[List of know issues for Windows 10 technical preview](http://microsoft-news.com/list-of-known-issues-in-windows-10-technical-preview-january-build-9926/)

Answer (score -1):

The pin sign in option is broken on the technical preview, it simply dose nothing. If you change to the consumer release version it works fine. I also had this problem but there's no way to make the pin work.