# PIN based login in Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, windows-10

Can't find PIN based login on my laptop with Windows 10 Home. Is it available at all in win 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Start menu, then settings (the "cog" icon) and then select "Accounts"

On the left you should see "Sign-in options", click that and the PIN setting should be in the options on the right.

[image]

Comment: I have just checked and I can see the option there in both Home and Pro editions of Windows 10.

Comment: From which version of Windows is this screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot is from Pro, but as I mentioned I have the exact same options on the Home edition that I have available. Well, not quite exact, as I have not set up a pin on that machine it shows "Add" instead of the "Change" and "Remove" buttons

Comment: I'm sorry, but I asked which __version__, not edition. A version number please...

Comment: @FleetCommand  Ah, sorry. Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.953). The latest AFAIK.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/875186/how-to-add-remove-windows-10-pin-sign-in suggests that pin sign in was available in RTM but broken in Technical Preview, so (in theory) the version should be unimportant.

Comment: The version number was useful to me. You have my gratitude for obliging me.